# How to load a password protected PDF form using PDFBOX

Tags: java, pdfbox

How to load a password protected PDF form using PDFBOX

I have a small piece of code to load  non protected PDF form

```
  PDDocument pdfDoc;
  pdfDoc = PDDocument.load(filePath);
```

Can any one help me out ..
Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Try this code :**

```
private void openPDFDoc(final File pdfFile) throws Exception {
        File originalPDF = pdfFile;
        PDFParser parser = new PDFParser(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(
                originalPDF)));
        parser.parse();

        PDDocument originialPdfDoc = parser.getPDDocument();

        boolean isOriginalDocEncrypted = originialPdfDoc.isEncrypted();
        if (isOriginalDocEncrypted) {
            originialPdfDoc.openProtection(new StandardDecryptionMaterial("password"));
        }
    }
```

Comment: awesome ... its working ...  Thanks for u r quick response @SAN3

Comment: Why the encrypted document text extraction is much slower than normal one? 5~10 times slower. Is there anyway to speed up?

Comment: Too many errors in the code.

Answer (score 10):

You can just use

```
public static void main(String[] args){
PDDocument pd;
try {
     File input = new File("p.pdf");  // password protected PDF file from where you would like to extract
     pd = PDDocument.load(input,"your_password");
     pd.setAllSecurityToBeRemoved(true);

     //for printing pdf file data
     PDFTextStripper reader = new PDFTextStripper();
     String pageText = reader.getText(pd);
     System.out.println(pageText);
     } catch (Exception e){
     e.printStackTrace();
    } 
 }
```